# Styling Android Action Bar

Tags: android

I've a newly created project and the first thing I want to do is add and style an action bar. I made it the way they tell in their official tutorials and even tried some other ways but I just can't make it work.
After many tries, I decided to do something really basic but even like that I can't make it work.
This is what I have:

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>

</style>
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Another question is what is the difference between the @android:style/Theme.Holo, @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar or simply Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your first question?

Comment: Are you trying to add a custom action bar with your own views like textviews etc ?

Comment: I want to add an action bar and after customize it with color, add tabs and stuff like that. But right now I just want to do the simplest. Add an action bar and change the background color. This for api lvl 16 and above

Comment: IIRC, if you use `AppCompat` theme, you have to use `actionBarStyle` instead of `android:actionBarStyle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Using the Material Theme training](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#StatusBar), the Material theme (and AppCompat theme's which backport / use Material theming) use `colorPrimary` to color the action bar. Therefore your theme can be:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

You'll find more details on how to theme using AppCompat / Material in the [AppCompat v21 blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) and in [this pro-tip](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/AV2ooBWY1iy)

Comment: So AppCompact is the "new" action bar? And with it we can use the new toolbar widget? Is that it?

Comment: Yes, AppCompat is the easiest way to get a consistent, easy to style Action Bar on all API levels

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use this tools to generate `ActionBar` styles:

http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Good Luck!

Comment: it's deprecated. And if possible I would like and explanation So I understand what's going on the background

Comment: Deprecated doesn't mean it's not working, it means there are other options, between them oficial options like ToolBar. Now if you want to style your Action Bar you can use Theme.AppCompat.Light, about your another question the difference is that @android:style/Theme.Holo it's like a base theme,

Comment: Deprecated means that is not maintained anymore. And unless that is the only option I don't want to use it. Thanks anyway

Comment: Nope, It's a program element, component or tool that programmers are discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because a better alternative exists. However always you can find this link helpful: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Comment: @Nuno: did you also followed that part: `<!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>`?

Comment: Yes I also tried that and it doesn't work. But I will try it again and see if I didn't miss anything. So far the @ianhanniballake was the best solution.